# Wrong destination of ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS flag

Tags: android, kotlin, security, android-intent, settings

Using this flag ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS I do not reach the same section within the settings.
I will access the lock section of the additional screen. From the documentation "https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings" I have not found other flags that allow it. How can I fix it?

With Oppo A16s ColorOS 12.1 Android 12 land on the page "System security" (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHr3P.jpg), while with Samsung Galaxy A20e Android 11 land in "Biometric data and security" (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS8eA.jpg).

Comment: Device manufacturers can have those `Intent` actions go anywhere, or not support them at all.